DCGM_FI_PROF_PIPE_FP16_ACTIVE data collect
When I use dcgm-exporter to collect DCGM_FI_PROF_PIPE_FP16_ACTIVE data, I find that the data is as small as 0.001458, and the unit is still %, is this normal?fp16 active data
And this is the program I use for FP16 precision calculation
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

// Helper function to check for CUDA errors
#define CHECK_CUDA(call) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t err = call; \
        if (err != cudaSuccess) { \
            std::cerr << "CUDA error in " << __FILE__ << " at line " << __LINE__ << ": " \
                      << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl; \
            std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
        } \
    } while (0)

// Helper function to check for cuBLAS errors
#define CHECK_CUBLAS(call) \
    do { \
        cublasStatus_t status = call; \
        if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) { \
            std::cerr << "cuBLAS error in " << __FILE__ << " at line " << __LINE__ << ": " \
                      << status << std::endl; \
            std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
        } \
    } while (0)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Matrix dimensions
    int m = 8192;
    int n = 8192;
    int k = 8192;

    // Get the number of GPUs
    int num_gpus;
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaGetDeviceCount(&num_gpus));
    std::cout << "Number of GPUs: " << num_gpus << std::endl;

    // Allocate host memory
    half *h_A = new half[m * k];
    half *h_B = new half[k * n];
    half *h_C = new half[m * n];

    // Initialize input matrices
    for (int i = 0; i < m * k; ++i) {
        h_A[i] = __float2half(1.0f);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < k * n; ++i) {
        h_B[i] = __float2half(1.0f);
    }

    // Allocate device memory for each GPU
    std::vector<half*> d_A(num_gpus);
    std::vector<half*> d_B(num_gpus);
    std::vector<half*> d_C(num_gpus);
    std::vector<cublasHandle_t> handles(num_gpus);
    std::vector<cudaStream_t> streams(num_gpus);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_gpus; ++i) {
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaSetDevice(i));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A[i], m * k * sizeof(half)));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_B[i], k * n * sizeof(half)));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_C[i], m * n * sizeof(half)));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaMemcpy(d_A[i], h_A, m * k * sizeof(half), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaMemcpy(d_B[i], h_B, k * n * sizeof(half), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        CHECK_CUBLAS(cublasCreate(&handles[i]));
        CHECK_CUBLAS(cublasSetMathMode(handles[i], CUBLAS_TENSOR_OP_MATH));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaStreamCreate(&streams[i]));
        CHECK_CUBLAS(cublasSetStream(handles[i], streams[i]));
    }

    // Perform matrix multiplication
    half alpha = __float2half(1.0f);
    half beta = __float2half(0.0f);

    // Warm up
    for (int i = 0; i < num_gpus; ++i) {
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaSetDevice(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            CHECK_CUBLAS(cublasGemmEx(handles[i],
                                      CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N,
                                      m, n, k,
                                      &alpha,
                                      d_A[i], CUDA_R_16F, m,
                                      d_B[i], CUDA_R_16F, k,
                                      &beta,
                                      d_C[i], CUDA_R_16F, m,
                                      CUDA_R_16F,
                                      CUBLAS_GEMM_DFALT_TENSOR_OP));
        }
    }

    // Create CUDA events for timing
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventCreate(&start));
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventCreate(&stop));

    int loop = 10000;
    if (argc > 1) {
        loop = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    }
    std::cout << "loop: " << loop << std::endl;

    // Start timing
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventRecord(start, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < loop; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_gpus; ++j) {
            CHECK_CUDA(cudaSetDevice(j));
            CHECK_CUBLAS(cublasGemmEx(handles[j],
                                      CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N,
                                      m, n, k,
                                      &alpha,
                                      d_A[j], CUDA_R_16F, m,
                                      d_B[j], CUDA_R_16F, k,
                                      &beta,
                                      d_C[j], CUDA_R_16F, m,
                                      CUDA_R_16F,
                                      CUBLAS_GEMM_DFALT_TENSOR_OP));
        }
    }

    // Stop timing
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventRecord(stop, 0));
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventSynchronize(stop));

    float milliseconds = 0;
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop));

    // Calculate FLOPS
    double flops = 2.0 * m * n * k * loop * num_gpus / (milliseconds / 1000.0);
    std::cout << "Time: " << milliseconds / loop << " ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FLOPS: " << flops / 1e12 << " TFLOPS" << std::endl;

    // Clean up
    for (int i = 0; i < num_gpus; ++i) {
        CHECK_CUBLAS(cublasDestroy(handles[i]));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaFree(d_A[i]));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaFree(d_B[i]));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaFree(d_C[i]));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaStreamDestroy(streams[i]));
    }
    delete[] h_A;
    delete[] h_B;
    delete[] h_C;

    return 0;
}

I want to know what the normal data size should be and how I should collect it
